# call a method while `ngFor` creates element

Tags: angular, angular5

I requires the element width from the loop, how to call the method on create the element from `ngFor` loop. i tried this not works. I am trying to call a method in my component. not in directive.

here is my try:

```
<ul class="cart-card">
    <li *ngFor="let size of sizes" class="cart-card--content" 
    [ngClass]="{'active': activeSize == size}"
    (click)="setServiceBySize(size)"
    (onCreate)="loopMethod(size)">//not calls
      <div class="cc-content-desc">{{appProps[sizeMap[size]['title']]}}</div>
      <div class="cc-content-image-xs" [ngClass]="'icon' + size" ></div>
      <div class="cc-content-desc1">{{appProps[sizeMap[size]['desc1']]}}</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply move the function call part into content of `li`.

```
<ul class="cart-card">
  <li *ngFor="let size of sizes" class="cart-card--content" 
    [ngClass]="{'active': activeSize == size}"
    (click)="setServiceBySize(size)">

    {{ loopMethod(size) }} 
    ...
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: works fine. can i conditionally call this method like : `{{ loopMethod(size) :activeSize == size}}`

Comment: @3gwebtrain you can use `Conditional expression` or simply embrace the function call with `ngIf` expression.